# Is the SharePoint Online PowerShell module compatible with PowerShell 7.1.3 (core)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have two versions of PowerShell installed on my Windows 10 desktop - Windows PowerShell (5.1) and PowerShell core (7.1.3).

I've installed the Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell module (version 16.0.21213.12000) in both environments. However, I'm not able to connect from PowerShell core. I get the error " The term 'connect-sposervice' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet..."

It will work if I explicitly import the module using the -UseWindowsPowerShell parameter. This displays a number of warnings about unapproved verbs.

I can't find any information on whether the Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell module is supported in PowerShell core or not. Is this an issue with my environment? Should I stick to using Windows PowerShell for now?

Answer (score 2):

The SharePoint Online PowerShell module can compatible with PowerShell 7(core) .

Note: Minimum PowerShell version--PowerShell 2.0

[image]

You can refer to the below posts:

- [Microsoft Releases PowerShell 7](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2020/03/04/microsoft-releases-powershell-7.aspx)
- [PowerShell 7 is out, compatibility mode saves most Office 365 modules](https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/2912/powershell-7-is-out-office-365)

Comment: Thanks @EchoDu_MSFT, the second article link that you provided also says that you need to use the -UseWindowsPowerShell switch when using PowerShell Core. 

I can see where it mentions the minimum version of PowerShell, but it doesn't indicate if it is supported in PowerShell core. From what I have read so far, it sounds like the Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell module must be run in compatibility mode to work in PowerShell Core

Comment: Hi, Ivan Wilson. Yes, you are right.